# Show that $|z_1 + z_2|^2 + |z_1 - z_2|^2 = 2|z_1|^2 + 2|z_2|^2$. Find a corresponding result for a finite set $\{z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n\}$.

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Suppose that $z_{1},z_{2}\in\textbf{C}$. Show that

$$|z_{1} + z_{2}|^{2} + |z_{1} - z_{2}|^{2} = 2|z_{1}|^{2} + 2|z_{2}|^{2}$$

Use induction to find a corresponding result for a finite set $\{z_{1},z_{2},\ldots,z_{n}\}$ of complex numbers.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Based on the fact that $|z|^{2} = z\overline{z}$, it results that
\begin{align*}
|z_{1} + z_{2}|^{2} + |z_{1} - z_{2}|^{2} & = (z_{1} + z_{2})(\overline{z_{1}+z_{2}}) + (z_{1} - z_{2})(\overline{z_{1} - z_{2}})\\\\
& = (z_{1} + z_{2})(\overline{z}_{1} + \overline{z}_{2}) + (z_{1} - z_{2})(\overline{z}_{1} - \overline{z}_{2})\\\\
& = |z_{1}|^{2}  + z_{1}\overline{z}_{2} + \overline{z}_{1}z_{2} + |z_{2}|^{2} + |z_{1}|^{2} - z_{1}\overline{z}_{2} - \overline{z}_{1}z_{2} + |z_{2}|^{2}\\\\
& = 2|z_{1}|^{2} + 2|z_{2}|^{2}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Now I am curious about the corresponding version to the finite set $\{z_{1},z_{2},\ldots,z_{n}\}$.

Any comments or contribution to my question?

Comment: Perhaps, the generalized version the question is aiming for is: $$\sum_{\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\ldots,\epsilon_n\in\{-1,+1\}}\,\left|z_1+\epsilon_2 z_2+\epsilon_3 z_3+\ldots+\epsilon_nz_n\right|^2=2^{n-1}\,\sum_{k=1}^n\,|z_k|^2$$ for all $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! Is there a geometric interpretation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem is known as [Apollonius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Apollonius%27s%20theorem%20is,median%20bisecting%20the%20third%20side%22.) written in $\mathbb{C}.$
It relates a median of a triangle to its sides (the lengths), or alternatively, the diagonals and the sides of a parallelogram.

A possible generalization with geometric interpretation ($n$-dimensional Euclidean space with inner product) provides this
[A generalization of Apollonius' theorem](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/20c3/983147e8ae4060bbab1968b43ebe12007a31.pdf?_ga=2.232224223.1754661821.1593759939-1298520262.1593759939) by Aaron J. Douglas